# Can I make git merge --ff act like --ff-only?

Tags: git

I sometimes want to do a `--ff-only` merge, and it's a little awkward to tab-complete, because `--ff` exists. But `--ff` is the default behavior, and I can't imagine ever wanting to specify it explicitly. Can I make `--ff` a synonym for `--ff-only`? I know I can make an alias like `ff-merge`, but I'm not thrilled about that solution. I'd also be happy with a solution that causes `--ff<TAB>` to complete to `--ff-only`.

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Bash?

Comment: @PaulHicks GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering the bit

> I'd also be happy with a solution that causes --ff to complete to --ff-only.

In bash, find which script is used to configure your git completions.  On my system it's `/etc/bash.completion.d/git-completion.bash`.

In there, find the bit specifying the options for git merge.  In my script, there's a variable `__git_merge_options`.  Your best bet is to search for `--ff-only`.

In that variable, remove `--ff`, so that only `--ff-only` and `--no-ff` (and other unrelated options) remain.

Save and source that script.

Voilà.

Comment: Thanks for adding the accent to my voila!  My answer looks that bit more, I dunno, *génial* now ;)